# how to pass the function name to be used in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

i have the following json template

template.py

```
from string import Template

test1 = Template(u'''\
{
    "data": {
       "name": "$name"
    }
}
''')
```

and to generate the JSONs I use
JSONGen.py

```
import template

class JSONGen:
    result1 = template.test1.safe_substitute(
        name = 'SomeName'
    )
    print(result1)
```

now that works, it produces the JSON but i'm trying to create a function that accepts the template name and calls it something like

JSONGenV2.py

```
import template

class JSONGenV2:

    def template_func(self, templateName):
        generatedTemplate = template.templateName.safe_substitute(
            name = 'SomeName'
        )

        print (generatedTemplate)

    template_func(test1)
```

now what i want to achieve is to use 'templateName' contents to be the template to call, as it is right now

```
template.templateName.safe_substitute
```

gives me an error saying 'templateName' doesn't exist, how can 'templateName' be a changed to the value passed in tihs case 'test1' so it would call

```
template.test1.safe_substitute
```

Thank you

Comment: You have to rethink your question title, so others can find your question better

Comment: That is not a safe way to generate JSON. The "safe" in the method name doesn't mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr), usage like this:

> **`getattr`**(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, *default* is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

Applied to your code:

```
class JSONGenV2:

    def template_func(self, templateName):
        generatedTemplate = getattr(template, templateName).safe_substitute(
            name = 'SomeName'
        )

        print (generatedTemplate)

    template_func(test1)
```

Comment: thank you @idlehands this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to convert a template name to instance of the actual template.
I would define a dictionary with the keys being the template name, and value being the template instance.

```
test1 = Template(...)
test2 = Template(...)
templates = {
    'test1': test1
    'test2': test2
}
```

Now in your method you could use the templates dictionary to get the instance of the template you requested:

```
def template_func(self, templateName):
    generatedTemplate = templates[templateName].safe_substitute(
        name = 'SomeName'
    )
    print (generatedTemplate)
```

And you would call the method like so: `template_func('test1')`